# vue.js 2 inputs number and percentage how to bind the model

Tags: vuejs2

I have a downpayment form that have two inputs. One for dollar amount and one for percentage. I also have a slider that changes the percentage.

```html
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Down Payment</label>
                    <div class="flex-row d-flex">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="downPaymentComputed" />
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="dpPercent">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mt-3 pt-4">
                        <vue-slider
                                v-model="dpPercent"
                                :tooltip="'always'"
                                :min="0"
                                :max="100"
                                :tooltip-formatter="formatter1"
                        ></vue-slider>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

in the script

```js
let app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        delimiters: ['${', '}'],
        components: {
            VueSlider: window['vue-slider-component']
        },
        data: {
            formatter2: v => `$${('' + v).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')}`,
            formatter1: '{value}%',
            payment:null,
            downPayment: {{ property.price*0.2 }},
            dpPercent:'20',
            price: {{ property.price }}
        },
        computed:{
            downPaymentComputed(){
                return this.price*(this.dpPercent/100)
            }
        },
```

In this configuration when I use the slider or enter the percentage, the downpayment changes. But when I enter new downpayment, nothing happens.

How do I bind so that when I change either the downpayment or the percent or the slider all inputs get updated?

EDIT: Thanks Phil, you pointed me in the right direction. I binded the values and then used on:change methods to update the other values

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" v-on:keyup="updateDP()" v-model="price" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" v-on:keyup="updatePercent()"  v-model="downPayment" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-on:keyup="updateDP()" v-model="dpPercent">
```

Comment: You've bound your `<input>` to a computed property without a setter so you are correct in that nothing will happen. Please explain what _should_ happen with some examples.

Comment: Also, your formatters should be methods, not functions in `data`

Comment: the formatters are props for the vue-slider component

Comment: Doesn't mean they can't (and shouldn't) be methods